# Attaching a specific fragment to a springboot thymeleaf project

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf, bootstrap-5

I have a navbar with a list. One of the elements in the list is a dropdown, which consists of one entry. On click of this entry, I would like to see a fragment of another html page in the project.

I have a navbar html file:

```
<div th:fragment="navbar">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03"
                aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false"
                aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0"> 
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a
                            class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#"
                            id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                            role="button"
                            data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
                            Projects 
                         </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" 
                                href="projects/sample.html#content"> ProjectList</a> <!--error-->
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </nav>
    </div>
```

And the project structure:
I have a folder named  *projects* inside src/main/resources, and within the *projects* folder, I have an html file *sample.html* and it has a fragment *content*

```
<div th:fragment="content">
        
</div>
```

---- UPDATE---

adding an image:
[image]

So currently, I want a fragment to be shown only when I click on the element in the dropdown "ProjectList". So I am thinking the link should happen in the href tag?
But not able to understand how.
any guidance here would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

If projects/sample.html is your template forlder, then try:

```
<div th:insert"~{projects/sample :: content}"></div>
```

If you want to change loaded template in real time (on click) you can:

- Use dynamic loading: This question is close to yours: [when click on list item hide other items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22692712/when-click-on-list-item-hide-other-items)
- Load the div, hide it by CSS and display it with javascript: [How to show and hide a simple <ol> list with onclick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17561093/how-to-show-and-hide-a-simple-ol-list-with-onclick)  (and to use JS with thymeleaf [Javascript function call with Thymeleaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26526037/javascript-function-call-with-thymeleaf) )
- Lastly, if you ould like to load the full content depending on the current URL, I think you're taking the problem on the wrong end. Every page should include the header/menu/footer (by referencing them as insert), and use th:href to load content depending on the url (see [Thymeleaf using path variables to th:href](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33753975/thymeleaf-using-path-variables-to-thhref))

Comment: But that creates a separate <div> fragment. I want it to be shown on the click of the drop down (ProjectList).. so the href needs to be modified right?

Comment: @RPK Where (in the navbar) do you want to see the content fragment ? Also, what's in the "content" div ?

Comment: please check the update

Comment: When I click, I should open a new fragment containing tabular info, which is provided by the "content" fragment

Comment: @RPK I've update the answer